# How to check in jQuery if an element has content in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a website in which I want to check whether element has any content in it.

Below is my `html code`. I have mentioned **condition#1** where `opacity-pointseven` class should be added through script.

```
<div class="featured-block">
   <a href="/" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
         <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">   
            <img src="">              // (condition#1)
         </figure>
         <div class="featured-block__content">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="featured-block__title">Trans Mountain Pipeline: NEB Releases New Report, Recommends Approval </h1>
            <h1 class="featured-block__tag"> More Coverage</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I tried in the following way, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").not(":empty") && $(this).find(".featured-block__tag").not(":empty")) {
                $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven");  // For condition#1
            } 

        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: so whats is really the problem of this?

Comment: This following script is checking for non-existing `featured-block__title` and `featured-block__tag` classes as well inside the `div.featured-block__item-inner` and adding `opacity-pointseven` in img tag.

 `else if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").not(":empty") && $(this).find(".featured-block__tag").not(":empty")) {
                $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointeight");`

Comment: @Beginner Did you get my point ?

Comment: ah I see you want to check if this classes didn't exist in this container? correct me if I',m wrong

Comment: No, I want to check for these classes inside div.featured-block__item-inner but it should check if there is content inside for both of them i.e condition#1

Comment: @Beginner I have added condition#1 in the html code above.

Comment: why 2 questions ?? when you can get answer in one question only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114183/how-to-add-a-class-in-javascript-jquery-if-an-element-has-content-in-it

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try something like this in Javascript unless it must be done in Jquery.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".featured-block__item-inner").forEach(function(itemInner){ 

 var blockTitle = itemInner.querySelector(".featured-block__content .featured-block__title");
 var blockTag = itemInner.querySelector(".featured-block__content .featured-block__tag");
 var blockImage = itemInner.querySelector(".featured-block__image, .img-fit");

 if(!(blockTitle && blockTag && blockImage)) return;  

 if(blockTitle.innerText = "" && blockTag.innerText="") {
    blockImage.classList.add("default-opacity");
 }
 else if (blockTitle.innerText != "" && blockTag.innerText !="") {
   blockImage.classList.add("opacity-pointseven");
 }
  .....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the element has no content or child elements inside, right?

If that is your problem then you can use this code to get the html content of the element (**the output of this code is *string***)

```
 $(this).find(".featured-block__title").html()
```

To check whether its content is empty or not, you can use the condition below

```
 if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").html().trim() == "") {
    $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("default-opacity");
 }
```

You can change your script with this one.

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".featured-block__item-inner").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").html().trim() == "" && $(this).find(".featured-block__tag").html().trim() == "") {
            $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("default-opacity");
        } else if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").html().trim() != "" && $(this).find(".featured-block__tag").html().trim() != "") {
            $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven");
        } else if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").html().trim() != "" && $(this).find(".featured-block__tag").html().trim() == "") {
            $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven");
        } else if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").html().trim() == "" && $(this).find(".featured-block__tag").html().trim() != "") {
            $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven");
        }

    });
})
```

Comment: wrap $(this) in local variable for better performance.

Comment: you can use $(this).find(".featured-block__title").html().length ==0 for better approach

Comment: @Florenz I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined`

Comment: @Florenz I want to check if there is no content inside it.

Comment: @flash you can use this to check if there's no content inside the element 
`if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").html().length == 0) { //your code here }` (this is also based on Negi Rox's comment)