# How to add a class in Javascript/jQuery if an element has content in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I am working on a website in which I want to check whether element has any content in it.

Below is my html code. I have mentioned **condition#1** where `opacity-pointseven` class should be added through script if classes `featured-block__title` and `featured-block__tag` have content in it.

```
<div class="featured-block">
   <a href="/" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
         <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">   
            <img src="">              // (condition#1, where opacity-pointseven needs to be added)
         </figure>
         <div class="featured-block__content">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="featured-block__title">Trans Mountain Pipeline: NEB Releases New Report, Recommends Approval </h1>
            <h1 class="featured-block__tag"> More Coverage</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I tried in the following way, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").not(":empty") && $(this).find(".featured-block__tag").not(":empty")) {
                $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven");  // For condition#1
            } 

        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over parent div and find the child items and then add the class over there.

Here in the example, I am getting `$('.featured-block__item-inner')` as a parent and then finding items inside it.

```js
$('.featured-block__item-inner').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").not(":empty").length > 0 && $(this).find(".featured-block__tag").not(":empty").length > 0) {
    $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven"); // For condition#1
  } else {
    $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("default-opacity");
  }
})
```

```css
.opacity-pointseven {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.default-opacity {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featured-block">
  <a href="/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">
        <img src="">
      </figure>
      <div class="featured-block__content">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="featured-block__title">Trans Mountain Pipeline: NEB Releases New Report, Recommends Approval </h1>
        <h1 class="featured-block__tag"> More Coverage</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">
        <img src="">
      </figure>
      <div class="featured-block__content">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="featured-block__title"></h1>
        <h1 class="featured-block__tag"> More Coverage</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I did the same.

Comment: Sounds good, I have a quick question. When there is no content inside `featured-block__title` and `featured-block__tag` classes, the script should be like this https://jsfiddle.net/j0evb72y/

Comment: @flash I would like to handle that using else condition. check my edited code.

Comment: looks good, but I am wondering if there is any mistake in my fiddle ? Your else statement looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @flash No need to check twice when you know what you want to do. and nothing wrong with your fiddle. you can use else to add alternate class

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620596/add-class-in-javascript-jquery-when-a-particular-timezone-is-selected-from-ui). Its not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

i hope the following script will heplful.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    if ($(".featured-block__title").text().length != 0 && jQuery('.featured-block__tag').text().length != 0 ) {
        $(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven");  // For condition#1
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit a bit in your code
`.not(":empty")` to `.html()`

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        if ($(this).find(".featured-block__title").html() && $(this).find(".featured-block__tag").html()) {
                $(this).find(".img-fit img").addClass("opacity-pointseven");  // For condition#1
            } 

        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="featured-block">
 <a href="/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit">   
         <img src="">              // (condition#1, where opacity-pointseven needs to be added)
         </figure>
         <div class="featured-block__content">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="featured-block__title">Trans Mountain Pipeline: NEB Releases New Report, Recommends Approval </h1>
            <h1 class="featured-block__tag"> More Coverage</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        if ($(".featured-block__title").html() != undefined && $(".featured-block__title").html() != "" && $(".featured-block__tag").html() != undefined && $(".featured-block__tag").html() != "") {
                $(".featured-block__tag").addClass("opacity-pointseven");  // For condition#1
            } 

        });
    })
</script>
```

Above is changes with your provided code.
in jquery you can find classes or Ids directly without using `this` object.
this is only required where you are in looping of some specific element (ie. inside Div loop).